# Need help with INI file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ini

Here is the deal, I am going through an INI file with some code. The idea is to return all of the categories found in the INI file with a regex, and then set at an arraylist = to results.

So here is the code:

```
    switch -regex -file $Path
    {
        "^\[(.+)\]$" {
            $arraylist.Add($matches[1])
        }
    }
```

However, the function returns not only the categories but also a count of the categories. For example, if the INI file looks like this:

```
[Red]
[White]
[Blue]
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
Red
White
Blue
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList.Add() returns the index at which the item was added.  This is why you see the numbers.  Just cast that statement to void e.g.:

```
[void]$arraylist.Add($matches[1])
```

or pipe to Out-Null

```
$arraylist.Add($matches[1]) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thank you! I acutally just changed it to this:

$index = $arraylist.Add($matches[1]) | Out-Null

And that fixed it.

Comment: You don't need to do both.  If you capture the output in a variable like $index you no longer need to pipe to Out-Null.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$al = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$cat = switch -regex -file $env:WINDIR\system.ini { "^\[([^\]]+)\]$" { $_ -replace '\[|\]'}}
$al.AddRange($cat)
```

Comment: Note that in this version the `$cat` variable already contains the collection of results in an array, which has first-class support in PowerShell, making the ArrayList unnecessary.  See also [Get-Help about_arrays](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315313.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to reproduce the problem you're seeing but cannot do it. Here is a recreation of the code that I'm using to test with:

```
("[Red]","[White]","[Blue]") | Out-File Test.ini -Encoding ASCII
$Path = (get-item Test.ini)
$arraylist = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$matches = @()
switch -regex -file $Path {
    "^\[(.+)\]$" {
        $arraylist.Add($matches[1]) 
    }
}

$arrayList
```

When this is executed, I get the following output:

```
Red   
White    
Blue
```

Is there something I'm missing that your code does not show?

Comment: No idea why it didn't recreate it for you. It was doing what Keith said it was.

Thanks.